# How to disable image detection if there is already a detected image

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, image-recognition

I have the, in my opinion, simple problem of disabling image detection with the AR Camera. I have the problem, that my app detects an image from the image library and spawns an object etc. everything according to plan.

But the problem is that if move the camera over another detectable image, it recognizes it. This is bad not because it spawns something additionaly but because you can "collect" the images in my app, so it unlocked the other detected one even though it shouldn´t.

So how can I disable image detection without turning off the AR-Camera?

I so far tried to simply disable the "ARManager" and the "ARTrackedImageManager" script (.enabled=false), but it didn´t solve my problem, because the app still detects other images.

Hope I could explain what my question and problem is properly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Need some code.  Tried SetActive(false)? - SetActive for gameObjects, enabled for components.  Adding boolean flags?  Ignored a certain Layer?

Comment: Thats the problem, I don´t know what to disable. I tried the 2 already mentioned managers (with .enabled).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what library you're using to detect the image. Generally, most marker tracking libraries will create a marker object in your Unity scene. You can disable these marker objects after you find one, and only leave the marker you're interested in. Make sure you also set the number of tracked images to 1 so you won't accidentally find two markers in one frame.

Comment: I´m using the Unity internal AR library, I don´t know and can´t seem to find the name right now.

Comment: So the answer above should do. Unity also provides controllers and managers for you dos enable and disable a marker in their demo code but you can really easily just enable and disable the marker Game Object /  component.